# When running gradle task through teamcity ,getting following issue

Tags: java, api, gradle, bintray, jcenter

Could not determine artifacts for javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.1.1

> Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.1.1/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.$%7Bpackaging.type%7D'.
> Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.1.1/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.$%7Bpackaging.type%7D'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request

Comment: I think `jcenter` is deprecated in the latest gradle version

Comment: Current ,we are using gradle version 3.4.1